# How can I resume a training job in Sagemaker script mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

In non-script mode for Sagemaker training jobs with Tensorflow, I was able to specify a checkpoint path in S3 with `checkpoint_path`.

However, in script mode this parameter is disabled.

How can I start from most recent checkpoint for a Sagemaker Tensorflow training job in Script mode?

Answer (score 1):

with script mode, the parameter you're looking for is `model_dir`

docs: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html#adapting-your-local-tensorflow-script